# FastAPI + SQLAlchemy - Updating Same Record in PostgreSQL

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy, orm, fastapi

I have a sever application with rest API to update the status of a record.
Example schema:

`| uuid(PK) | Status |`

The Status can be A, B, C, D which is ordered, i.e. B comes after A, C comes after B and D comes after C.

This server application is running in Kubernetes with multiple pods and same database instance.

When the client sends two status updates very close to each other (milliseconds difference) in order C->D.
Sometimes the on the server side, the Request D is processed first and C after. So we end up with the final status as C. It is possible to go from A->D, A->C, B->D as well, and not backwards.

What is the best way to avoid this situation? I am new to sqlalchemy ORM so details would certainly help.

If two workers have read the record and know the status is B, one of them is going to commit to the DB as value D, and the other as C. Is there a way to put a lock at the record/row level that workers can't even read the record until the other yields the lock?

Comment: See documentation [Select ... for update](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/sql-select.html)

Comment: thank you - SELECT FOR helps!